# How to read zip file content without unzipping (in compressed format) using Python

Tags: python, zip

I have to publish a zip file to the server. This involves reading the file and uploading.

```
zfile=zipfile.ZipFile(x,"r")
data = zfile.read()
zfile.close()
```

This won't work as `read()` needs an additional argument-filename to uncompress.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just open the file with a normal `open` call if you don't want to decompress the zip.

Comment: To add to Andrew's comment: use 'b' binary mode to be Windows compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may ignore the fact the file is a ZIP file and open it as you would any file:

```
with open(x, "rb") as zfile:
    data = zfile.read()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob, it worked!
i didnt try the "rb" mode earlier which was the key. (For anyone reading, use rb mode with caution as advised by Python docs)